# MySQL query not inserting data (php)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, xampp

Sorry, probably a stupid code error, but my website is failing to insert the data into the database.
From submit.php:

```
$questionID = 2;
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name");
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO data ('questionID') VALUES ('$questionID')");
```

My table is called 'data' and the first field is named 'questionID' and is of type int.

Comment: Column names should be in bacticks (`), not quotes (').... only quote string literals.... as you're using MySQLi, why aren't you using bind variables?

Comment: Thanks for the fix. What are bind variables?

Comment: You could fix this "stupid code error" yourself by simply [checking for errors](http://php.net/mysqli_error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bind values is a better approach to doing this insert:

```
$questionID = 2;
$dbh = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name");
$insert = $dbh->prepare("insert into data (questionID) values (?)");
$insert->bind_param("i", $questionID);
$insert->execute();
```

[More reading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

There are a number of reasons to use bind values, predominant arguments being protection against injection and preventing hard parses.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - since when was recommending good practise worthy of a downvote..... especially as the question that the OP asked in response to my own original comment was "What are bind variables?"

Comment: @MarkBaker This answer does not even touch on what the problem is (the single quotes). Recommending good practice is fine, but you should first answer the actual question.